# display xml into table in jsp page

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp

im having this xml:

```
<Results><Row><COLLATION_NAME>latin2_bin</COLLATION_NAME><CHARACTER_SET_NAME>latin2</CHARACTER_SET_NAME><ID>77</ID><IS_DEFAULT/><IS_COMPILED>Yes</IS_COMPILED><SORTLEN>1</SORTLEN></Row><Row><COLLATION_NAME>utf32_esperanto_ci</COLLATION_NAME><CHARACTER_SET_NAME>utf32</CHARACTER_SET_NAME><ID>177</ID><IS_DEFAULT/><IS_COMPILED>Yes</IS_COMPILED><SORTLEN>8</SORTLEN></Row></Results>
```

for any query the number of rows is different, how can i display it into a table in a jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with xslt, is like a style sheet for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Results">
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="COLLATION_NAME"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="CHARACTER_SET_NAME"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="IS_DEFAULT"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="IS_COMPILED"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="SORTLEN"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

More information in http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/ :)